# How to switch between values within one column in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have a fairly large csv file with more than 130,000 rows and they are already sorted by value like this:

```
_Row#_  _Word__  _Part of Speech_  _Value_
     1  Too      Adverb                  3
...
  5000  Many     Adjective               5
...
 94999  Entries  Noun (Plural)          20
 95000  To       PoS                    21
...
130000  Manage   Verb                   21
```

If I have selected the value column, is there a way for me to move from the 130000th item to the 94999th item because it is the next item by Value?

Comment: Can you sort by Value?

Comment: @tigeravatar I did, if you see in the Value column they are sorted that way. I should have mentioned that though, I'll edit it to reflect that.

Comment: Alternately, use ctrl+f to perform a Find for the value you're looking for

Comment: Beyond that, I can only imagine that it would require a VBA solution

Comment: @tigeravatar all the values between 95000 and 130000 are the same. In this example, they are all 21.

Comment: My temporary solution was to go through and annotate in the column to the right a break with number break at each boundary.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a column comparing the `_value_` of the current row with the `_value_` of the previous row you could then filter on `FALSE`, i.e `=D4=D3`, not sure if that helps but then you would have unique (first of or last of depending on your test logic) `_Value_` rows.

It only works if sorted by `_Value_` of course and only useful if you just want to see those, otherwise you will need to switch the filter off and on (that or do a find next on `FALSE` in that column).

Answer (score 1):

Very simple (no error checking etc) VBA macro to search down until the value changes:

```
Sub GotoNextDifferentRowValue()
    Dim x As Variant
    Dim y As Variant
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Selection.Cells(1, 1)
    x = rng.Value2

    Do
        Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0)
        y = rng.Value2
    Loop Until (x <> y)

    rng.Activate
End Sub
```